# How to get information of IOS/Android storage with IONIC?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to get this information:

1. Total space of device
2. Free Space of device

I try with different plugins and It doesn´t work correctly, Someone found the solution for that?

Thnks a lot for your colaboration!

Comment: Have you tried `cordova-plugin-extended-device-information` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with that, but It is only android.... I want to another plugin because I need for IOS too.

Comment: Have you tried `ionic file`? It has method `getFreeDiskSpace`.

Comment: Hi Perfect Square, Yes I tried that... but this library doesn´t have to get TOTAL space on disk for IOS, do you know of any?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqli-cordova-disk-space-plugin

It is both for android & ios. I am also using it for my project.